# hide ACF fields when they are empty

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i use the following code for a wordpress template with custom fields:

```
<?php

// vars
$special_product = get_field('special_product', $term); 

if (!get_field('special_product') )
if ( $special_product): ?>
<div class="container_wrap container_wrap_first main_color sidebar_right 
template-shop">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-left-sp single-product-main-image alpha">

    <a class="lightbox-added lightbox avia_image" href="<?php echo $special_product['image']['url']; ?>"  rel="lightbox" title="" rel="product_images[grouped]">
    <img src="<?php echo $special_product['image']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $special_product['image']['alt']; ?>" /></a>

    <div class="thumbnails">

    <a class="lightbox-added lightbox avia_image thumb-image" href="<?php echo $special_product['thumb1']['url']; ?>"  rel="lightbox" title="" rel="product_images[grouped]">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="<?php echo $special_product['thumb1']['url']; ?>" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail" alt="<?php echo $special_product['thumb1']['alt']; ?>" /></a>
           <a class="lightbox-added lightbox avia_image thumb-image" href="<?php echo $special_product['thumb2']['url']; ?>"  rel="lightbox" title="" rel="product_images[grouped]">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="<?php echo $special_product['thumb2']['url']; ?>" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail" alt="<?php echo $special_product['thumb2']['alt']; ?>" /></a>
           <a class="lightbox-added lightbox avia_image thumb-image" href="<?php echo $special_product['thumb3']['url']; ?>"  rel="lightbox" title="" rel="product_images[grouped]">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="<?php echo $special_product['thumb3']['url']; ?>" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail" alt="<?php echo $special_product['thumb3']['alt']; ?>" /></a>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="container-right-sp single-product-summary">
    <?php echo $special_product['description']; ?>
    <a class="avia-slideshow-button avia-button avia-color-orange avia-multi-slideshow-button" href="<?php echo $special_product['product-link']['url']; ?>">
    Zum Produkt</a>
    </div>    

        <div>
</div>
</div> <!--close container -->
</div>   <!--close container_wrap --> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

With the code if (!get_field('special_product') ) i tryed to hide the custom field when it is empty but it doesnt work. How can i hide it?

Best regards

Chris

supplement:
The Output for &special_product (when custom fields are empty) is:

Array ( [image] => [description] => [product-link] => [thumb1] => [thumb2] => [thumb3] => )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running print_r($special_product) you got:

```
Array ( [image] => [description] => [product-link] => [thumb1] => [thumb2] => [thumb3] => )
```

Because the empty field returns an empty array and NOT nothing at all, it can never be deemed empty, you need to check a key from the array to see if the keys value is empty.

I told it to check the image field of that array to see if it's empty.

If your product wont always have an image then feel free to change it to check for a field that will always be present.

Here is your working code:

```
// vars
$special_product = get_field('special_product', $term); 

<?php if ( $special_product['image'] ): ?>
    <div class="container_wrap container_wrap_first main_color sidebar_right 
    template-shop">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container-left-sp single-product-main-image alpha">
                <a class="lightbox-added lightbox avia_image" href="<?php echo $special_product['image']['url']; ?>"  rel="lightbox" title="" rel="product_images[grouped]">
                <img src="<?php echo $special_product['image']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $special_product['image']['alt']; ?>" /></a>

                <div class="thumbnails">
                    <a class="lightbox-added lightbox avia_image thumb-image" href="<?php echo $special_product['thumb1']['url']; ?>"  rel="lightbox" title="" rel="product_images[grouped]">
                    <img width="100" height="100" src="<?php echo $special_product['thumb1']['url']; ?>" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail" alt="<?php echo $special_product['thumb1']['alt']; ?>" /></a>
                    <a class="lightbox-added lightbox avia_image thumb-image" href="<?php echo $special_product['thumb2']['url']; ?>"  rel="lightbox" title="" rel="product_images[grouped]">
                    <img width="100" height="100" src="<?php echo $special_product['thumb2']['url']; ?>" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail" alt="<?php echo $special_product['thumb2']['alt']; ?>" /></a>
                    <a class="lightbox-added lightbox avia_image thumb-image" href="<?php echo $special_product['thumb3']['url']; ?>"  rel="lightbox" title="" rel="product_images[grouped]">
                    <img width="100" height="100" src="<?php echo $special_product['thumb3']['url']; ?>" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail" alt="<?php echo $special_product['thumb3']['alt']; ?>" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-right-sp single-product-summary">
                <?php echo $special_product['description']; ?>
                <a class="avia-slideshow-button avia-button avia-color-orange avia-multi-slideshow-button" href="<?php echo $special_product['product-link']['url']; ?>">
            Zum Produkt</a>
            </div>    
        </div> <!--close container -->
    </div>   <!--close container_wrap --> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That's how it works via the documentation so your get_field must not be working correctly, does it execute the value if you use the_field, as your $term might not be working

Comment: mh.. ok! i have no idea how to fix it. The fields are always shown (im empty or not)

Comment: the custom field are only displayes if i use this in the beginning:

`$special_product = get_field('special_product', $term); 

 if (get_field('special_product', $term) ): ?>
    <div class="container_wrap container_wrap_first main_color sidebar_right`....

Comment: Updated answer, also what's the field type of special_product

Comment: yes this is the code is used... but it shows all div containers also when custom fields are empty :-(

Comment: print_r($special_product) when it's empty and add the output to your question please

Comment: ok, this works... but i dont understand :-) What you did with this: `<?php if ( $special_product['image'] ): ?>`?

Comment: yes it works but i dont understand this `<?php if ( $special_product['image'] ): ?>` What are you doing there? Can yu explain with words? Thanks!!

Comment: I've explained in the answer, it's at the top :)